# Event when clicking a tel link in mobile firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events, tel

I'd like handle an event when a `tel:` link is clicked on a website and send it as an event to analytics. The following code seems to work fine on the desktop, but fails to send an event on a mobile.

```
function report_tel_click() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'tel-link', 'click');
}
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    var link = links.item(i);
    if (link.href.startsWith("tel:")) {
      if (link.addEventListener) { link.addEventListener("click", report_tel_click); }
      else if (link.attachEvent) { link.attachEvent("onclick", report_tel_click); }
    }
  }
});
```

The standard behaviour works without issues - the phone app comes up after clicking the link. Does this have to be handled in some specific way?

Besides verifying that the code appears in the page contents, I don't know how to debug this on a mobile device. I'm testing on mobile Firefox on Android.

Follow up: this seems to be specific to mobile firefox. It works on mobile chrome as well.

Code present on [live website](https://northeastfamilymedicine.com.au)

Comment: At least on Google Chrome you can connect your Desktop Chrome with your Android Chrome and debug directly via computer on your device.

Comment: Here is a link how you do remote debugging https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: https://www.optimizesmart.com/event-tracking-in-google-tag-manager-v2-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `onclick event` for the `ontap event`

Comment: Do you have any documentation describing the `ontap`? It's not part of https://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/

Comment: Try with this event: https://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#the-touchend-event